# Checkbox angular is duplicating within other blocks in Ngfor

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a component that injects a child that is an auxiliary component. In the parent component I have an `NgFor` that duplicates the child component and inside the child I have another `ngfor` that creates some checkboxes.

The problem is that when I check just one box it also checks the same box in another group. How can I resolve it?

Parent component:

```
<div class="bloco-bilhete" id="bilhete1" style="padding: 15px" *ngFor="let divs of div">
<app-checkbox [Itens]="Listdays" (ItensReturn)="setDayReturn($event)"</app-checkbox>
</div>
```

child:

```
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-filho" *ngFor="let i of Itens; index as n">
      <input id="checkAceite{{n}}Div{{Div}}" class="form-check-input checbox-espaco" type="checkbox" [checked]="i.value" (change)="i.value = !i.value">
      <label for="checkAceite{{n}}Div{{Div}}" style="font-size: 12pt">{{i.nome}}</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want the check not to duplicate in other blocks.

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by *another* group. The code provided only has 1 group in the parent. Create a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/) code which duplicates the issue and provide it here. Creating a test bed might actually help you identify the problem. If not, we can recreate what you are seeing.

Comment: they're all bound to the same "Itens" array.  You need to change that.

Comment: can you please provide that code in Stack Blitz ?  so I will see it and resolve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's likely due to the checkboxes in different app-checkbox instances share the same model. So when you check a checkbox in one, it affects across all instances.

So try something like:

```
<div class="bloco-bilhete" id="bilhete{{divId}}" style="padding: 15px" *ngFor="let div of div; let divId= index">
  <app-checkbox [Itens]="div.Listdays" (ItensReturn)="setDayReturn($event)" [divId]="divId"></app-checkbox>
</div>
```

Inside child comp.

```
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-filho" *ngFor="let i of Itens; let n = index">
    <input id="checkAceite{{n}}Div{{divId}}" class="form-check-input checbox-espaco" type="checkbox" [checked]="i.value" (change)="i.value = !i.value">
    <label for="checkAceite{{n}}Div{{divId}}" style="font-size: 12pt">{{i.nome}}</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Also a bit out of scope but you should add name attribute to checkboxes when working with them in a form

Comment: With ur comment, I resolved it. The problems ocorred because of input itens, I believe the angular thinks that  iteration array is of the same scope in ngFor. I separed this variable.

Answer (score 0):

For resolve this problem I change my format array to:

New:

```
groups = [
{
  groupName: 'Group 1',
  items: [
    { id: 1, label: 'Opção 1', checked: false },
    { id: 2, label: 'Opção 2', checked: false }
  ]
},
{
  groupName: 'Group 2',
  items: [
    { id: 1, label: 'Opção 3', checked: false },
    { id: 2, label: 'Opção 4', checked: false }
  ]
}
```

];

Old:

```
items: [
    { id: 1, label: 'Opção 3', checked: false },
    { id: 2, label: 'Opção 4', checked: false },
    { id: 1, label: 'Opção 1', checked: false },
    { id: 2, label: 'Opção 2', checked: false }
  ]
```